# Generating dynamic IQueryable<T> from EF

Tags: entity-framework, iqueryable

I have a table full of orders, where each order has a state (for example: `failed, denied, pending, cancelled or success`)

How can I write a dynamic query to return orders, by state, where I'm passing *one or more* states?

ie something like all failed, denied or cancelled orders:

```
IQueryable<MyType> query = from o in Model.Orders
                           where o.OrderStatus == ("Failed" || "Denied" || "Cancelled")
                           select o;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the Contains method

```
string[] status = {"Failed", "Denied", "Cancelled"};

IQueryable<MyType> query = from o in Model.Orders
                           where status.Contains(o.OrderStatus)
                           select o;
```